# Django - Pass a variable from the Template to the Manager

Tags: django

I am building myself a little budgeting app. I am using this Manager:

```
class AccountMonthlyManager(MonthlyCalculationManager):

    def transactions(self, date_str):
        date = get_this_month_and_year(date_str)
        entries = self.related_set().filter(date__month=date[0], date__year=date[1]).aggregate(total=Sum('amount'))
        return entries.get('amount', 0)
```

along with this model:

```
class Account(models.Model):
    begin = models.FloatField()
    weekly_change = models.FloatField()
    fixed_value = models.FloatField(null=True)
    income = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    monthly = AccountMonthlyManager()
    objects = models.Manager()
```

I want to show the total from all the transactions for each account in the template kinda like this:

```
{% for account in view.budget_accounts %}
<tr class="dataLine budget" data-id="{{ account.id }}">
    <td>{{ account.label }}</td>
    <td>{{ account.monthly.transactions }}</td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
```

However, the manager needs a the date string, which is in my url.

```
url(r'^budgets/(?P<slug>[^/]+)/$', views.BudgetView.as_view(), name="budgets"),
```

I'm looking for a way to accomplish this which doesn't involve me overloading my view with a lot of code for this single purpose. Right now, all I am doing is this:

```
def budget_accounts(self):
    return Account.objects.filter(income=False, fixed_value=None)
```

I need a way to get this url string back to the manager, so it can deliver the correct totals!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your urls.py? You should be able to add a parameter in a URL so that you translate from `/budgets/2017-12/` to something like `view_budgets(monthyear)`. Based on a sample from [Django URL Dispatcher](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/urls/) you should be able to do something like:

```
url(r'^budget/([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})/$', views.budget),
```

and change the budget() function to:

```
def budget(request, year, month):
```

or similar. Not sure how you are getting the template into budget_accounts so I am not sure if that is really your display view function. But urls.py is the key and is quite powerful - if you work at it then you could have a big web site that never has any traditional parameters on GET - only for security purposes (and perhaps to keep the URLs from getting TOO long) and for POST.

Comment: I see what you are saying. I could definitely get the data into the view.. My problem is that the view function is only fetching a queryset. I am iterating through the queryset inside the template.

Comment: I guess I should be handling this all in the view, but getting all of this logic out of the view was the reason I moved everything into the manager in the first place!

Comment: I've added the url

Comment: So, if I move the queryset itself into the manager, I think this will work out! Thanks for the help!